# Executing remote script by curl doesn't work

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, scripting

I'm trying to run one script (which installs and setups Postgres DB) from another script (**test.sh**). The problem is that the script which is called inside my script is remote (online on GitHub) and it doesn't work.

I tried to call the script three different ways.

1. locally - works
2. remotely using `bash <(curl...` - raises error
3. remotely using `curl ... | bash -s` - downloads script and hangs...

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# this works correctly (it's the same but local)
sudo bash postgres/setup.sh 

# this raises "bash: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory"
sudo bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/milano-slesarik/sh-ubuntu-instant/master/postgres/setup.sh)

# this hangs
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/milano-slesarik/sh-ubuntu-instant/master/postgres/setup.sh | sudo bash -s
```

The last one probably downloads the script but then hangs...

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1532  100  1532    0     0   8281      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  8281
```

Do you know how to make it work?
I want my scripts to be online so I don't have to clone/download then all the time.

Comment: Reasons you should not run a script piped from a remote server like that: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/213401/215097

Comment: @LéaGris I understand but this is my repository so I suppose it's quite safe since nobody can modify the code.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it hangs when you run `curl -s $script |bash -s` seems to be a misbehaviour in the script itself, at least as long as you run it like that. You can debug this by adding the `-x` flag to the `bash` command. Then you can see the following message spawning in an endless loop, due to the `while` statement contained in the script:

```
++ read -p 'Do you wan'\''t to install postgres? [y/n]: ' yn
++ case $yn in
```

Also, as long as you are running the script this way, to avoid this behaviour I would remove those lines in which the script is expecting some kind of user input. If that is not the case, the easiest way is just to download it via `curl` and then run it locally from your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This may achieve what you wanted :

```
sudo bash -c "bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/milano-slesarik/sh-ubuntu-instant/master/postgres/setup.sh)"
```